# How to shape a Pandas DataFrame for LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to correctly shape a `pandas` *DataFrame*  into a format compatible with `Keras`'s method `timeseries_dataset_from_array()`. The main issue is about the high number of features in the dataset, which implies to use a *for* loop:

```
x_reshaped = [tf.reshape(x_train.iloc[:-seq_length, column].values, (-1, 1))
              for column in range(len(x_train.columns))]
```

When I run:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x_reshaped, y_reshaped,
                                                          sequence_length=seq_length,
                                                          batch_size=bs)
```

I get this error message `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`, because `x_reshaped` is considered as a *list* of vectors, instead of a matrix.

I have tried, also, to create the training matrix by `tf.TensorArray()`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call that high-dimensional, because a Pandas DataFrame normally has 1D data. You don't need the reshaping operation or the for loop. You can pass the DataFrame directly into the Keras function:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.DataFrame({'features1':    [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
                   'features2':    [4., 3., 2., 1., 0.],
                   'predictions':  [5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]})
```

```
   features1  features2  predictions
0        0.0        4.0          5.0
1        1.0        3.0          6.0
2        2.0        2.0          7.0
3        3.0        1.0          8.0
4        4.0        0.0          9.0
```

Pass the column in the Keras function:

```
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
     data=df[['features1', 'features2']],
     targets=df['predictions'],
     sequence_length=3)

x, y = next(iter(ds))

print(x.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([3, 3, 2])
```

It will look like this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[[0., 4.],
        [1., 3.],
        [2., 2.]],
       [[1., 3.],
        [2., 2.],
        [3., 1.]],
       [[2., 2.],
        [3., 1.],
        [4., 0.]]])>
```

Now that it has a time step dimension, it can be passed into an LSTM layer.

```
lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1)

lstm_layer(x)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.11129456],
       [0.14443444],
       [0.18482907]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: My data has a timestamp column, and the timestamp intervals are irregular. The timestamps and data are generated when an object is detected. I noticed in another tutorial that the date time column was dropped but in that case the data was regular; generated every 10 minutes. So, would I include the timestamp column in my case? If so, where would it fit in? Would it be part of the data=[[features1...]]?